# How to use an angular scope variable outside the scope it is defined in

Tags: angularjs

I have a service like below, which fetches the `id` of a student from a RESTful (Laravel) API and returns it.

```
       .factory('Student', function($http)
    {
        return  {
            getId: function(adm_no) {
                return $http.post('/api/student/getId',{adm_no:adm_no})
                .then(function(response)
                {
                    return response.data;
                }, 
                function(httpError)
                {
                    Notifier.error(httpError.data.error.message,'Error ' + httpError.status + " Encountered");
                });
            }
        }
    }

   )
```

Then i use it as follows in a controller.

```
    $scope.adm_no = 98;    
    Student.getId($scope.adm_no)
        .then(function(response)
        {
            $scope.id = response;
        });
  // probably i want to use the `$scope.id` when a particular event takes place (or even in another query to the server alltogether), but outside the above function scope e.g.

    $scope.showId = function()
    {
      alert($scope.id);
    };
```

Now, the question is how I can use the a scope variable declared in a 'local scope' outside the scope, for the usage above shows that `$scope.id` is undefined?

Comment: What do you mean by 'outside the scope'?

Comment: I think the problem is you dont return promise from your service.

Comment: @micronyks, i mean like i have done above, using `$scope.id` outside the `.then()` function it is declared in

Comment: @shobull, like now for example how can i restructure it?

Comment: @GThuo in your service, you should return only "return $http.post('/api/student/getId',{adm_no:adm_no})" and delete other lines. Now you can use .then(...) in your controller or whatever.

Comment: but this scope remains available to you through out your controller.

Comment: @shobull, i see. i had thought that if i do it this way i will keep my controller 'cleaner' in that success or error would all bee handled in the service. Or what is the better way of achieving that goal?

Comment: @GThuo Ok than you can't use .then(...) in your controller... Just make assignment like $scope.id = Student.getId($scope.adm_no);

Comment: ok, though it will tel me the ID is undefined, probably because no result has been returned from the server yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$scope.id` is undefined in function `$scope.showId()` because when you call an alert function, your post request hasn't finished yet and so `$scope.id` hasn't been initialized (it is beeing executed asynchronously). Try this:

```
$scope.showId = function() {
  if ($scope.id) {
    alert($scope.id);
  }    
};
```

Anyway you don't have to use `$rootScope` in this case. Your property `id` from `$scope` is accesible from your whole controller. You have to wait for the ajax post request and than it is initialized.

Comment: thats right. in code, how do i ensure that the ajax request has processed and initialized `$scope.id` successfully before i use the `$scope` variable later in the controller?

Comment: Well, i managed to solve it or refactor the problem somehow. The explanation above is right, that the post request has not finished executing and therefore the values have not been initialized yet. I solved it by rethinking my work, and especially by resolving (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) all my needed values before i load the page. Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In place of $scope you have to use `$routescope` variable to get id in  other place as-

```
Student.getId($scope.adm_no)
    .then(function(response)
    {
        $routescope.id = response;
    });
```

Comment: ook and is it `$routeScope` or `$rootScope`?